# Where to install Kibana (and tools like it)

Tags: macos

I'm following the guide [Install Kibana with .tar.gz](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/targz.html), and not sure where I should put it on a Darwin/OS X system. I know I can probably put it where I want, but wondering if there is a designated/standard place on my system for such tools. On this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-elasticsearch-logstash-and-kibana-elk-stack-on-centos-7), they use Yum which puts it into a Yum repo, but I'm not sure if that's what I want to use. My Elasticsearch is installed at `/usr/local/elasticsearch-6.0.0` with a symbolic link to it at `/usr/local/elasticsearch`.

Answer (score 1):

On macOS the canonical place to install Unix software is `/usr/local/`, with the usual set of `bin`, `lib`, `etc` etc. beneath it. Going with this your installation of `elasticsearch` would seem to be bit odd but that is probably easy to fix.

You could also go with [Homebrew](https://brew.sh) which allows an easy installation of a lot of Unix software (and which uses `/usr/local` as a base as well). Both Kibana (4.4) and Elasticsearch (2.4) are available through Homebrew.